# How do I config Logstash.conf for different structure rows in file?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

How do I config Logstash.conf for different structure rows in file?
**(filter { match })**

Comment: Different rows? Sorry a litte bit more details would be great

Comment: different content like: First Row: I like choclate, Second Row: Harry Potter is great.

Comment: You can specify file as output and by default it will write each event in a single line

Comment: Of course this is done. My ques How I manipulate different content rows in the filter { match }

Comment: If your data looks like "I like choclate" you can use grok{} and create regular expressions. Update your question with examples of your data, maybe we can help better...